# ASP.NET application can't copy the file from local machine to FileShare

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to copy zip file from my local machine to the fileshare using asp.net web application. The permission to fileshare is set up for our admin account that has got read and write permission. When I am using code on my local machine, everything works as it should and the file is coppied over to fileshare on the server. However, when I run the application on the server, it doesn't copy the file over.

Settings of web application on the server are following:
Physical Path Credentials are set for specific user (admin account)
Authentication is enabled only for anonymous authentication

The code is:

```
If (fileSize < 2100000) Then
                    Dim fileName As String = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName)
                    Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)

                    If (extension = ".zip") Then
                        ' Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
                        Dim UpPath As String
                        Dim UpName As String
                        UpPath = savePath & txtDummy.Text & "\"
                        UpName = Dir(UpPath, vbDirectory)
                        If UpName = "" Then
                            MkDir(UpPath)
                        Else
                            'log the info
                        End If
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(UpPath & "\" & fileName)
                    Else
                        ' log info                         
                Else
                    ' log info
                End If
            Else
                'log info
                Exit Sub
            End If
```

Could you please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. The reason why I couldn't copy the file to the fileshare is that I had to set up admin account for authentication and for application pool. I did the following in IIS7:

1. **SET UP AUTHENTICATION** - Right Click on your web site in IIS > Double click Authentication > Click Anonymous Authentication > click on Edit in Actions pan > Set Specific user to your admin account
2. **SET UP APPLICATION POOL** right click on application pool your application uses > select advanced settings > change Identity in Process Model to admin account.

I hope this will help to somebody else.